# Cannot push git repo to OpenShift

Tags: git, openshift

I am trying to push repo in the cloub but I am getting following error :

```
rockvilla@CodeMachine:/var/www/nisargaresort$ git push
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 473 bytes, done.
Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: restart_on_add=false
remote: httpd (no pid file) not running
remote: /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/abstract/info/lib/util: line 982:     /var/lib/openshift/0afc2085c8d341ef85f5c8057885035c/app-    root/runtime/repo/.openshift/action_hooks/post_stop_php-5.3: Permission denied
remote: Failed to stop php-5.3
To ssh://0afc2085c8d341ef85f5c8057885035c@nisargaresort-    syndication.rhcloud.com/~/git/nisargaresort.git/
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://0afc2085c8d341ef85f5c8057885035c@nisargaresort-    syndication.rhcloud.com/~/git/nisargaresort.git/'
```

There is nothing related to this problem on the net? Can anyone help me here? thanx in advance
Also if i do this

```
rhc app start -a nisargaresort -d

Contacting https://openshift.redhat.com
Problem reported from server. Response code was 500.

DEBUG:
Cartridge return code: 121

Exit Code: 143
api_c: placeholder
broker_c: namespacerhloginsshapp_uuiddebugaltercartridgecart_typeactionapp_nameapi
API version:    1.1.3

RESULT:
Node execution failure (invalid exit code from node).  If the problem persists please     contact Red Hat support.
```

Comment: The following link has an answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500811/unable-to-push-changes-to-git-openshift

Answer (score 0):

Let's use this forum post to track the issue:

https://openshift.redhat.com/community/forums/openshift/not-able-to-push-repo

Thanks