# Unable to push changes to git openshift

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

Hi guys I could do that but not anymore i.e. I could upload changes to openshift git.

I have tried resetting git repo, push by force but no success.

Here is the log that I get through:

> Amits-MacBook-Pro:api  $ git push origin  master --force
>
> Counting objects: 33, done. Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
>
> Compressing objects: 100% (32/32), done. Writing objects: 100%
>
> (33/33), 1.46 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done. Total 33 (delta 16), reused 0
>
> (delta 0) remote: Postgres already stopped remote: Stopping NodeJS
>
> cartridge remote: No such file or directory -
>
> /var/lib/openshift/.../app-deployments/2015-07-19_07-38-12.349/metadata.json
>
> To ssh://...@api-tmate.rhcloud.com/~/git/api.git/  ! [remote rejected]
> master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push
> some refs to 'ssh://...@api-tmate.rhcloud.com/~/git/api.git/'

Answer (score 0):

Found a quick solution here now that login through SSH and delete everything that you have within app-deployments folder.

if you in the mac then use this command to delete everything within app-deployments.

> rm -rf *

```
* NOTE: Your current directory should be app-deployments from where you will run this command.*
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same phenomenon but I noticed it was happening when I was running in '--no-auto-deploy' mode. When I changed it back to auto-deploy, the life-cycle execution ensured the expected effect of the push.